# Django: autoslug -> custom slugifier

Tags: python, regex, django, slug

I have a prob. I'm trying to create a custom slugify functiom. I use [django.autoslug](http://bitbucket.org/neithere/django-autoslug/downloads). Due to autoslug documentation I was able to create a custom slugifier, but it needs to be improved and I do not know how do I realize that.

So I have a string (book title) i.e. `.NET Framework 4.0 with C# & VB in VisualStudio 2010`. I want to slugify it so that it looks like this: `dotnet-framework-4point0-with-cshapr-and-vb-in-visualstudio-2010`

My current function looks like this:

```
def custom_slug(value, *args, **kwargs):
    associations_dict = {'#':'sharp', '.':'dot', '&':'and'}
    for searcg_char in associations_dict.keys():
       if search_char in value:
          value = value.replace(search_char, associations_dict[search_char])
    return def_slugify(value)
```

As you can see, my function replaces all dots `.` with `'dot'`. So my string will be changed into `dotnet-framework-4dot0-with-csharp-and-vb-in-visualstudio-2010`

I suggest, I should use RegEx, but I don't know how to do this and how do I replace matched string with right 'dot/point-replacement'

Ideas ?!

P.S. Sorry for bad English

Comment: nothing. Its a bells and whistles but I tried to realize 4point0 and din't get it, so I asked a question =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
point = re.compile( r"(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)" )
point.sub( value, "point" )
```

to change the `.` s that should be `"point"` , and then do `str.replace` to change the others.

#### Explanation

`point` matches a `.` which is sandwiched between two digits.

`(?<=spam)ham(?=eggs)` is a (positive) [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It means "match `ham`, as long as it is preceded by `spam` and followed by `eggs`". In other words, it tells the regex engine to "look around" the pattern that it is matching.

Comment: Thanx, but what is  `(?<=)` and `(?=)` standing for ? 
I know only that `\d` is for digit, `\.` matches the dot and `()` captures the matched string.....

Comment: Edited the post: it's a lookaround: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html